# First moment of area by integration

Tags: integration

I have an issue with the integral computing the fist moment of area (please, take a look at the attached file).
Integration gives an answer which doesn't satisfy the correct one[image] (also given in attached file).
Please, explain, if possible, where do I make a mistake while setting up the integral?

Thanks in advance,

Sergey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of these is correct because $Q$ is a quantity (a number with units).

We have $\mathrm{d}A = (2\,\mathrm{mm}) \cdot \mathrm{d}s_1$, $z(s_1) = s_1/2$, we take $\mathrm{u}$ to be the units of $s_1$ and of $z$, and \begin{align*}
\iint_A z(s_1) \,\mathrm{d}A  &=  \int_{0\,\mathrm{u}}^{100\,\mathrm{u}} \frac{s_1}{2} (2 \,\mathrm{mm}) \cdot \mathrm{d}s_1  \\
    &= (1 \,\mathrm{mm}) \left. \frac{s_1^2}{2} \right|_{s_1 = 0\,\mathrm{u}}^{100\,\mathrm{u}}  \\
    &= 5 \,\mathrm{u}^2\cdot\mathrm{m}  \text{.}
\end{align*}

Alternatively, $s_1(z) = 2 z$, $\mathrm{d}A = (2\,\mathrm{mm})\cdot \mathrm{d}s_1(z) = (2\,\mathrm{mm})\cdot 2\,\mathrm{d}z$, $\mathrm{u}$ is still the units of $s_1$ and of $z$, and \begin{align*}
\iint_A z \,\mathrm{d}A  &=  \int_{0\,\mathrm{u}}^{50 \,\mathrm{u}} z (2\,\mathrm{mm})\cdot 2 \,\mathrm{d}z  \\
    &= (4 \,\mathrm{mm})\left. \frac{z^2}{2} \right|_{z = 0 \,\mathrm{u}}^{50 \,\mathrm{u}}  \\
    &= 5 \,\mathrm{u}^2\cdot \mathrm{m}  \text{.}
\end{align*}